# For loop for windows not working

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, directory

I am using the following for loop in a batch file.

```
for /f "delims=" %%D in (C:\BUGdb_update\sfr.txt) do (
echo %%D
)
```

My intention is for every line in sfr.txt, it should do something. even echo is not working for me.

```
for /F "delims=" %D in (C:\BUGdb_update\sfr.txt) do (echo %D )
```

It is just coming out from the loop.

Comment: look at `C:\BUGdb_update\sfr.txt`, where does the file come from? Look inside with an Hex Viewer. Format might be  UTF.

Answer (score 2):

try this (see my comment):

```
for /f "delims=" %%D in ('cmd /u /c type "C:\BUGdb_update\sfr.txt"') do (
echo %%D
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try both of these - they just have a pause there and are Endoro's solution.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%D in ('type "C:\BUGdb_update\sfr.txt"') do (
echo %%D
)
pause
```

Unicode:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%D in ('cmd /u /c type "C:\BUGdb_update\sfr.txt"') do (
echo %%D
)
pause
```